# Need help solving a functional equation

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to [\; 0 , \infty )$ be a function satisfying:
$$ f(x+y) - f(x-y) = f(x)\cdot (f(y) - f(-y) ) $$
$$ f'(0) = \log a $$
$$ f(0) = 1 $$
where $x,y > 0$ and $x,y \not = 1$.

Now, I tried putting $x = y$ and few random things, but seriously, I have no clue as to how to go about solving it.

Also, it'd be great if someone could give some nice resource where I can learn how to solve such equations, as I am very much new to these!

Comment: Are you sure about the conditions "$x,y>0$ and $x,y\ne 1$"?

Comment: I copied the question from a question paper, so I am pretty sure. Why? (and I think it applies only to the given condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $y = h$, and divide both sides by $h$. Add and subtract $f(x)$ on LHS, Add and subtract $f(0)$ on the RHS. You will end up with
$$
\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h} + \left(\frac{f(x-h) - f(x)}{-h}\right) = f(x)\left [\frac{f(h) -f(0)}{h}  + \left(\frac{f(-h) - f(0)}{-h}\right)\right]
$$
Assuming $f$ is differentiable everywhere, take a limit to get
$$
f'(x) = f(x)\log(a)
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Awesome idea!$ $

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are unwilling to assume differentiability outside $x=0$, consider the sequence $a_k=f(x_0+k\,h)$ for some fixed $x_0$ and $h$. Then you get the linear recursion

$a_{k+1}-qa_k-a_{k-1}=0$ where $q=f(h)-f(-h)\approx 2h\,\log a$.